# Is print the only way to display something in .py file

Tags: python

In the python command line, I can do

```
>>> a
array([ 0,  1,  3, 10,  1,  0,  0,  3,  6])

>>> print a
[ 0  1  3 10  1  0  0  3  6]
```

But in a .py file, I can only do print, but not directly 'a'. What if I want to see the whole `array([ 0,  1,  3, 10,  1,  0,  0,  3,  6])`?

Comment: What type is `array`, exactly? Is it the Python [`array`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) type?

Comment: `print 'array(%s)' % a`.

Comment: The python CLI is a read-eval-print loop: see [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: judging by the `str(a)` it is a numpy array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The interpreter usually shows what [`repr(object)`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#func-repr) returns, so:

```
print repr(a)
```

Example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([ 0,  1,  3, 10,  1,  0,  0,  3,  6])

In [3]: repr(a)
Out[3]: 'array([ 0,  1,  3, 10,  1,  0,  0,  3,  6])'
```